# Mirroring a PC to PC

Tags: mirroring, screen-sharing

I have a robot running windows 7 and I would like to mirror the screen from it to another PC. The robot internet connection isn't stable, but the WIFI is always connected. My question is, is it possible to mirror a PC to PC using WIFI connection only without internet access? and How?

Thanks...

Comment: What is your definition of mirroring? You could use a Windows Remote Desktop Connection depending on it.

Comment: @Seth Windows Remote Desktop would not work as it logs out the other user. But Teamviewer, VNC, etc would work.

Comment: I tried realVNC, but I think it needs an internet connection, and by mirroring, I just want to see the desktop of the robot's PC on a remote screen or PC.

Comment: realVNC does not require an internet connection, teamviewer does. If you don't mind that the robot PC does not have anything on the screen while you control that pc remotely, RDP is sufficient, though.

Answer (score 0):

See if [AirParrot](http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/) and [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) are what you need. AirParrot transmits over AirPlay protocol. Reflector receives AirPlay protocol transmissions.